# Help Figuring out Period of Trig Function

Tags: trigonometry

I'm working on a javascript project for hobby that I'm trying to get some neat effects working in. The issue is its been a long time since I was in trig and I'm having a hard time grasping exactly how to approach it.

The project is here: http://codepen.io/seckela/pen/EaZmBj

This should make it easier to visualize.

Each ball in the sequences uses the formula:

$$\frac{h}{2} \left(\;  1 + \sin\left(\; \frac{c}{f}\;\left( \frac{i}{x} + s \right) \;\right)  \right)$$

where:

- $h$ = height of the element
- $c$ = the frame count
- $f$ = period factor
- $i$ = current array position
- $x$ = ball size * ball count
- $s$ = wave shift

In this demo I loop through an array of "balls" and run the function on them based on the location they are in the array and the frame count (with all the other variables pre-set)

What I need to figure out is how to calculate on what frame (or relative frame c/f) each ball reaches it's peak. I can't for the life of me figure out the equation to solve for that.

Comment: By my reading of the code, the formula should be  $$\frac{h}{2} \left(\; 
1 + \sin\left(\; \frac{c}{f}\;\left( \frac{i}{x} + s \right) \;\right) 
\right)$$ which isn't *quite* what you've written above.

Comment: Thank you, you're correct actually, the grouping around it would suggest I missed my groupings.

Answer (score 0):

$\sin(z)$
is periodic with period $2\pi$
with peaks at
$\pi(2k+\frac12)$
for every integer $k$.

(The following is edited
to reflect the
modified question.)

In your case,
set
$\frac{c}{f}( \frac{i}{x}+s)
=\pi(2k+\frac12)
$
and solve for which ever
variable you want.

Comment: It looks like I had the equation wrong (corrected it in the original). Not sure how it changes the period function. If I were to solve each i for its c at peak, I'd just have to solve for C for each i with a similar formula to the one you provided right?

${c}
=\frac{{f}{x}\pi(2k+\frac12)}{i}
$

Correct?

Comment: I made the appropriate change to my answer.

Comment: I appreciate it. Sorry, its been a long time, what does k represent in the $2{k}$ part of the equation?

Comment: k is any integer. For the standard version of sin, k = 0.